# Select data from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following:

> Table1 IdTable1, IdTable2, IdTable3
>   Table2 IdTable2, Title
>   Table3 IdTable3, FName, LName

I Need the content of Table1 with the Title, FName, LName

I have tried

```
SELECT T2.Title, T3.FName, T3.LName  
FROM Table1 T1  
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.IdTable2 = T2.IdTable2  
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.IdTable3 = T3.IdTable3
```

All what I get is the Table2 with the other columns NULL or the 2 columns of Table3 with the first column NULL.

Table 1 Contains
1 2 1
2 2 1
3 2 5

Table 2 Contains
1 Mr
2 Madame

Table3 Contains
1 A B
2 C D
3 E F
4 G H
5 I J

The Results of all my Queries are
Madame Null Null
Madame Null Null
Madame Null Null
or
NULL A B
NULL A B
NULL I J

Comment: I keep staring at the table layout and am not really following with what the schema is.

Comment: You have Table2 twice, is that a typo, should the 3rd row say Table3?

Comment: I'm not seeing an obvious problem with the query.
Is it practical to share some of the actual data?

Comment: Nulls will appear when no matching records are found on the right side of a left join. Did you expect something different? If so why?

Comment: @user3149487 Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. You will get all matching records from all tables

Comment: There is no way that you have these exact data and this exact query and you get this (any of the two) output.

Comment: Could you post the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is fine as long as you want to return partial results.

Have you verified the actual data is correct?  You are using a `LEFT JOIN`.  This means rows in T1 will be returned even if there is no matching data in T2 or T3.  If there are no matching rows in one of those tables, the columns in that table will be NULL.

If you include all of the columns in T1 in your result set, you will see that there is indeed data in T1, but there is no matching data in T2 or T3.  In cases where T3 columns are NULL, that means there is data in T1 and T2 but not T3.

It looks to me like you've got a referential integrity problem.  You may need to add foreign keys with drop constraints or fix some application logic problems when creating or deleting records.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I checked my tables and there were no relationship between them, I should checked out when the query didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Table1 is a pivot table for Table2 and Table3. I will do something like below.

```
SELECT T2.Title, T3.FName, T3.LName
       FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2, Table3 T3 WHERE T2.IdTable2 = T1.IdTable2 and T3.IdTable3 = T1.IdTable3
```

Comment: Hi Kumar, thanks for the answer, but an error from the comma in the WHERE.

Comment: Edited it, Replaced **comma** with **and**

Comment: AND returns nothing and the OR returns 3 times the supposed results.

Comment: My Query is working see the results here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3086/13 . You have the duplicate entry in Table1 referring to 2,1

Comment: You are right Kumar, it works with the AND. The problem of my query was the tables are not connected with any Relationship. Thank you again.